# JS How to enable input after copy paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, prop

Ok so I have an submit button which is disabled, and once the user starts typing the button is enabled.
But it is not enabled if the user decided to copy and paste their email.
Here is the code:

JS:

```
$("._x86892465 ._field-wrapper input").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#colophon #_form_15_submit").prop("disabled", false).css({"cursor" : "pointer"});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="_form_element _x86892465 _full_width " >
              <label class="_form-label">
                Email*
              </label>
              <div class="_field-wrapper">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address..." required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="_button-wrapper _full_width">
              <button id="_form_15_submit" class="_submit" type="submit">
                Subscribe
              </button>
            </div>
```

I have tried using on change i.e `on("change", function() {});`

Not really sure how to go about this.
Anyone encountered this problem before.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onpaste` event

```
$("._x86892465 ._field-wrapper input").on("paste", function() {
    $("#colophon #_form_15_submit").prop("disabled", false).css({"cursor" : "pointer"});
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/vineeshmp/2m8utzye/

Answer (score -4):

```
$( "._x86892465 ._field-wrapper input" ).change(function() {
    $("#colophon #_form_15_submit")
    .prop("disabled", false).css({"cursor" : "pointer"});
});
```